# automatic, continues and real time data sending between two linux

Tags: python

i'm writing a python code and the output is some variables containing numbers.the numbers are changing continuously.i want to send these numbers from one linux on witch the code is running to another linux and there i wanna receive the numbers and use them to do sth.

but the data needs to be sent real time, automatic and continuously after the code has been ran on the first pc.i'm not familiar with web programming  or html but i'm asking if there is any simple way through LAN network,WIFI network, Web or other things for me to do this job

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @jpp I'm not sure the OP could provide an example of anything, it seems the question is more of a general design/architecture question than an actual issue.

Comment: @taylorthurlow, If that's the case, they should ask in Software Engineering SE rather than SO.

Comment: its absolutely an actual issue.i have a matrix of numbers as output of my code that is changing continuously and i need to send these numbers to another linux in any possible way that is automatic and real time.the whole code is too long.i can not share it here.